# Javascript search that matches the string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to do a search in the fruits array that matches the exact character position.

```
var fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Grapes", "Banana", "Guava", "Apricot", "Avocado", "Cherry", "Water Melon"];
```

If i type **a** then all fruit names that contains **a** are filtered. I need the fruit names that starts with **a** only.

```js
var fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Grapes", "Banana", "Guava", "Apricot", "Avocado", "Cherry", "Water Melon"];

$(document).ready(function () {
    row = '';
    i = 1;
    $.each(fruits, function (key, fruit) {
        row = row + "<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + fruit + "</td></tr>"
        i++;
    })
    $("table tbody").append(row);
})

$(".search").keyup(function () {
    $("table tbody tr").each(function () {
        if ($(this).find("td:eq(1)").text().toUpperCase().indexOf($(".search").val().toUpperCase()) != -1) {
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="search">
<table>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/114nx02k/1/)

Comment: Did you write that code yourself? It is as easy as changing that `!=-1` with  `==0`.

Comment: The code to reproduce the problem has to be part of the question itself and not only a link to an external resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line,

```
    if($(this).find("td:eq(1)").text().toUpperCase().indexOf($(".search").val().toUpperCase())!=-1)
```

with this line

```
if($(this).find("td:eq(1)").text().toUpperCase().indexOf($(".search").val().toUpperCase())==0)
```

and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Try this example

```js
var fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Grapes", "Banana", "Guava", "Apricot", "Avocado", "Cherry", "Water Melon"];

$(document).ready(function () {
    row = '';
    i = 1;
    $.each(fruits, function (key, fruit) {
        row = row + "<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + fruit + "</td></tr>"
        i++;
    })
    $("table tbody").append(row);
})

$(".search").keyup(function () {
    $("table tbody tr").each(function () {
        if ($(this).find("td:eq(1)").text().toUpperCase().indexOf($(".search").val().toUpperCase()) == 0) {
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="search">
<table>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/114nx02k/2/)